# Using procedure variables to create server-side prepared statements — MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Within procedures, why does using session-specific variables to store string queries work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_prepared_stmt` () BEGIN
    SET @q:="SELECT * FROM t1";
    PREPARE query FROM @q;
    #...
END$$
```

but using procedure variables not:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_prepared_stmt` () BEGIN
    DECLARE q TEXT;
    SET q:="SELECT * FROM t1";
    PREPARE query FROM q;
    #...
END$$
```

and instead throw the following error?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'q;
>
> END' at line 5

Is this just a quirk of the language?

Comment: The docs clearly states "user variable or string literal". Doesn't say why. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL standard variable syntax - all variables are declared/used with the @ symbol.

So, in your example, if you used:

`declare @q text`

or,

`declare @q nvarchar(4000)`

or anything similar, it will work - just follow the SQL spec for usage of variables and you should be fine, regardless of whether you are within a procedure or passing a parameter, or anything else.